# Removing a column of a 2D Array in C by overwriting its elements

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, 2d

I need help with understanding the mechanism of removing a column of a matrix. Say, if I had a matrix which looks as follows:

```
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
 1 2 3
```

I'd want to remove the second column so the whole matrix looks like this:

```
1 3 
1 3 
1 3
```

My assignment before this one was to write a code which removes all rows whose first element is divisible by 2. It looks as

```
for (i = 0 ; i < V ; i++)
{  /*V = ''height'' of matrix*/
    if (matrica[i][0] % 2 == 0)
    {       
        for (k = i ; k < V - 1 ; k++)
        {
            for (j = 0 ; j < S ; j++)
            {     /8 ''S'' width of matrix*/
                matrica[k][j] = matrica[k+1][j];
            }
        }

        i--;
        V--;
    }
}
```

Could I perhaps somehow modify my upper code so it can do the same but with columns?

Comment: You should name your variables something unambiguous, such as `row` and `column`.

Comment: You'd have to invoke the `memmove` function to shift elements of the array

Comment: In answer to your question: *Could I perhaps somehow modify my upper code so it can do the same but with columns?*  Of course you could modify the posted code.

Comment: The question isn't answerable without knowing the type on the matrix. Is this a true 2D array or some pointer-to-pointer arrangement? What's meant by removing: deleting that memory?

Comment: It is a true 2D Array. I have not used pointers to create one. The initial declaration of the matrix was   "matrica[100][100]" and after that I manually entered V and S.  The basic idea I had for the rows is that every time the variable "i" gets to a row that needs to be removed, it copies the row **after** it ( matrica[k][j] = matrica[k+1][j] ) into the one that needs to be removed. Simplified, when the loop gets to a row that needs to be removed, it **shifts** all other rows so the "heighth" of the matrix decreases by 1 (V--)

Comment: And no, this is not a dynamic matrix. Thanks for helping! I am sorry for not providing this information earlier.